# Eclipse project move from linux to windows 10 causes class not found errors

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

a little eclipse project works fine on linux where I started. It failes to load my own classes on the new machine which currently runs on windows 10.
It uses maven 3.0.1 on Linux and maven 3.3.9 on windows 10.
After transfered via git to the new machine I did not have .settings, .classpath or .project

than started

```
mvn clean
mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
mvn dependency:resolve
mvn install
```

to solve the error I tried all refreshes I could think of...still it seems not everything is found even as ctrl+shift+R does find these ressources

So this code worked before

```
Server server = new Server(Settings.PORT);
```

but failes now with with

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/Locker
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.(Server.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.(Server.java:109)

the import shows even the sources of

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;

any idea what else I could try ?

Comment: Does the project have directory or file names with blanks or non-ascii characters?

Comment: yes all maven targets gave a success message. the project does not have any spaces but I have to check if the code has strange charachters as it has been trasnfered via git

Comment: Are you using `jetty:run` (or any other goal in the `jetty-maven-plugin`) in any way?.  If not, then run `mvn dependency:tree` and report it's results in your question.

Comment: Hi Joakim, Since my company diced to move all java development to outside the company I do not work on that project or even java anymore